# How to examine a module/signature at ocaml top level?

Tags: ocaml

Please: I would like to examine a module's signature; is there a function to do this? Just typing the name of the module doesn't work:

```
# List ;;
Error: Unbound constructor List
```

In fact I want to do this for modules I define on the interactive top level.

Sorry if the answer is obvious - hard to search for this! Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard trick for this is to make a new module synonym:

```
# module Mylist = List;;
module Mylist :
  sig
    val length : 'a list -> int
    val hd : 'a list -> 'a
    val tl : 'a list -> 'a list
    . . .
    val sort : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
    val stable_sort : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
    val fast_sort : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
    val merge : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list
  end
#
```

**Update**

Since OCaml 4.02 this trick no longer works. Instead there is a toplevel directive for the purpose:

```
# #show_module List;;
module List :
  sig
    val length : 'a list -> int
    val hd : 'a list -> 'a
    val tl : 'a list -> 'a list
    . . .
    val sort : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
    val stable_sort : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
    val fast_sort : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
    val sort_uniq : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
    val merge : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list
  end
```

Comment: It used to be the only way to get this info. Things are different (and better) since OCaml 4.02.0.

Answer (score 5):

In OCaml versions >= 4.02, you can now also do this in the interactive interpreter:

```
# #show_module List;;
module List :
  sig
    val length : 'a list -> int
    ...
  end
```

Or just use `#show List;;`